# Fed Up: A Word Puzzle

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle, visual

[image]

Transcription of the clues:

```
Against the current
Assumed
Belief in the paranormal
Celestial explosion
Come together again
Dinners
Drug which acts to inhibit something
Indian currency
Keeping current
Kitchen storage area
LIKE THE LETTERS IN THIS CLUE
Recover from illness
Type of comedy
Type of comic book character
Ultimate
Volcanic event
Zoom-in camera shot
```

[Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OuHJRZdzzvb4XKZZL-MWB9_6PvbLz-O73yQkyQ4HcY0/edit#gid=657343545) (contains exaxctly the same information)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This puzzle is about

> **Ascending a message**

The clues can be solved as

> Against the current - **UPSTREAM**
>  Assumed - **SUPPOSED**
>  Belief in the paranormal - **SUPERSTITION**
>  Celestial explosion - **SUPERNOVA**
>  Come together again - **REGROUP**
>  Dinners - **SUPPERS**
>  Drug which acts to inhibit something - **SUPPRESSANT**
>  Indian currency - **RUPEE**
>  Keeping current - **UPDATING**
>  Kitchen storage area - **CUPBOARD**
>  LIKE THE LETTERS IN THIS CLUE - **UPPERCASE**
>  Recover from illness - **RECUPERATE**
>  Type of comedy - **STAND-UP**
>  Type of comic book character - **SUPERHERO**
>  Ultimate - **SUPREME**
>  Volcanic event - **ERUPTION**
>  Zoom-in camera shot - **CLOSE-UP**
>
>  Each of these answers contain the substring **UP**, and there is an up arrow on each row of the grid. Furthermore, we can fit all of the answers in the grid so that the *up* in each word is replaced by the arrows like so:
>  [image]
>
>  As a further confirmation that this is correct, all the neighbouring squares missing borders actually contain the same letter.
>
>  The last up arrow just below the grid indicates where we can read the final answer
>  **ASCENDING A MESSAGE**

Comment: Argh, you just beat me to the post by about two seconds! (Was literally finishing typing up my 'Finally...' line...) Well done, this is exactly what I have too +1

Comment: @Stiv Nice to be able to beat you for a change, usually I'm several hours behind you. :)